# Web browser control shows Navigation to the webpage was canceled

Tags: webbrowser-control

I have a web browser control in my MFC application, when I navigate to a https site, it shows "Navigation to the webpage was canceled", but it always OK with IE browser.
Added 
 "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\myapp.exe"
and
 "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\myapp.vshost.exe"
(value is 11000) in registry,
but the web browser control only work sometimes, and in most time, it cannot work, and shows "Navigation to the webpage was canceled". Refresh page will show "There is a problem with this website’s security certificate".

I built the project in debug mode (32-bit).
Any one knows how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Built application with VS2013 on Win7.

Comment: Use CHtmlView, seems it always work now.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3830/HTMLCtrl-with-dynamic-HTML-content